# Using OSM to develope android app

Tags: android, openstreetmap

**I have just started programming in JAVA and Android.** I have been able to make an android app in which i store markers in a MySql database which i fetch using PHP and display them in a map overlay. Also i have allowed adding markers to the database as well. I am doing all this using Google Maps API and i would also like to do the same using Open Street Map. I would be thankful if anybody gave me some hints on how to do this or some links that would be useful to me.  Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Mapsforge (http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/). It is designed to be a near drop-in replacement to Google Maps. It's not completely trivial, but they have a sample app in the source code, which shows the basic moves to accomplish some common results.

Another option is Osmdroid  (http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/). The main difference being that with Mapsforge you download a map file and render it on the device, so maps will be available even without a data connection. Osmdroid downloads tiles from OSM, much like Google Maps API does from Google Maps.